# Приложение C# не запускается

Tags: c#

Приложение на  C# не запускается на win7
На 8 и 10 всё Ок...

Я делал резервные копии типа, предыдущие версии... Так вот они работаю норм...а с некоторых пор перестало работать на 7... Причём изменения были такие же что и раньше просто увеличился объём...

Не запускается, это значит когда открываешь приложение, этот процесс зависает и никаких окон не отображается...
Я не говорю, что "все пропало", я хочу узнать кто встречался с такой задачей и как её быстро решить

Comment: версию .net framework меняли?

Comment: Нет, не менял, сегодня попробую... Но думаю, что в ней вряд ли заключается, потому что изменился грубо говоря только объём, и предыдущие версии работают...

Comment: @Breaker Если у вас/вашего знакомого есть машина на Win7, запустите ваше приложение на ней в режиме отладки и тогда уже выявите проблему